# two different versions of packages in package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have installed two packages `@svgr/webpack@5.5.0` and `css-what@5.0.1`. In this `@svgr/webpack@5.5.0` contains css-what version 3.4.2 but I installed it explicitly of version 5.0.1. Now which version of `css-what` will be installed

```
  ├─┬ @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
  │ └─┬ @svgr/plugin-svgo@5.5.0
  │   └─┬ svgo@1.3.2
  │     └─┬ css-select@2.1.0
  │       └── css-what@3.4.2
  └─ css-what@5.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

When all packages, including the root one - ie yours - `require('css-what')` they will use 5.0.1 - and when `css-select` `require`s it - it will use 3.4.2.